# Can I release a script that depends on both proprietary and GPL'd libraries to be run?

Tags: licensing, gpl, scripting

I'm writing my thesis project in GNU Octave. My project basically consists of a bunch of ".m" files that are written in Octave. I'm also using a proprietary (and unreleased) shared library developed by my supervisor.

To be able to access the library, I've written an OCT-file wrapper (dynamic extension for Octave). My question is: am I allowed to distribute my ".m" files that depend on both Octave internals and the proprietary library? I'm not going to distribute any dependencies nor the wrapper files, just the ".m" files. Is it illegal to distribute these (I don't mind being forced to release them under a specific license) if they depend on a proprietary piece of software to be fully functional? Even if it's just to document my experiments?

I've already asked at the Octave forums, but they were too passionate and aggressive and didn't give any useful arguments. I would like to hear facts, not ideology.

PS: I know I could use MEX, which is the only explicitly allowed means of communication with proprietary libraries in Octave. However, it's not possible for technical reasons to use MEX in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the FAQ quoted by Gustav, Octave DOES NOT force a license onto your .m files. You can release .m files under ANY license that you choose.

It sounds like Octave will force a license on the library you are using, if you want to distribute it. So if you need to release that, you'll have to work that out with your supervisor.

As far as I can see from my cursory look, .m files can't reasonably be considered derivative works. (If they were, then they'd be derivative works of the built-in Octave functions, and all .m files would have to be GPL.)

Since it's clearly the case (it says so in the FAQ) that all .m files don't have to be GPL, I would conclude that while you probably have to GPL the library to distribute it, there's no need to GPL your .m files.

Comment: Yes, but is it okay if I don't distribute the library at all? I don't care the program won't work for anyone else but me, I just have to enclose it with my thesis to document my experiments and ideas described in the text. Am I legally allowed to release something that doesn't work without the library? Or am I forced to release the library under GPL if it's needed by the ".m" files? (That's what the Octave folks say!)

Comment: @JanHadáček - Yes, I think that's OK. Since your .m files are NOT going to be GPL, there's no rule that says you have to release all of your dependencies along with them.

Comment: @JanHadáček: Apart from the copyright issue, you should also look into possible requirements from your university about full disclosure of the software you used in obtaining your results.

Comment: @Bart van Ingen Schenau I discussed this issue with my supervisor and he simply said I wasn't required to publish a working piece of software, simply because his library was a trade secret (it's not released yet). He said it's okay with university rules. So a long as it's okay with GPL to publish just a part of the sources, I should be fine I guess. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [FAQ has a useful section](http://wiki.octave.org/FAQ#Licensing_issues) about this:

> **If I write code using Octave do I have to release it under the GPL?**
>
> Code written entirely in the scripting language of Octave (interpreted
>   code in .m files) may be released under the terms of whatever license
>   you choose.

If your supervisor's library is written using the native plug-in interface, then according to the same section in the FAQ, *that library needs to be GPL*:

> Code written using Octave's native plug-in interface (also known as a
>   .oct file) necessarily links with Octave internals and is considered a
>   derivative work of Octave and therefore must be released under terms
>   that are compatible with the GPL.

However, that doesn't affect the licensing of your code, just of your supervisor's.

Comment: Thanks. I've seen that FAQ though. The problem here is, that my ".m" files depend on a proprietary library (and Octave). The Octave people claim this fact makes the situation exceptional. They say that the proprietary library becomes a derivative work of Octave in this case. I don't belive it and want to know if it's true.

Comment: Doesn't matter what your files depend on. If you're just distributing .m files, then you're allowed to. Under any license. You supervisor's code is a separate matter, and may need to be GPL'ed. But even if it is, that still doesn't affect your code's licensing.

Comment: Okay, makes sense. Actually, my supervisor doesn't use any GPL'd code. It's true that I do link the wrappers for his library with both Octave runtime and the library. However, I guess it should be fine unless I release the wrappers, right? If I get it right, GPL seems to allow linking with proprietary software, but not the distribution of the result.

Answer (score 0):

.m files are not required to be licensed GPL, so you can distribute them as you see fit.  Even if they were required to be licensed GPL, there's nothing in the GPL that requires you to publish working source code, or all of your source code, unless you also publish binaries built from that source code.

Part of the confusion on the Octave forums stems from the fact that a common way to try to circumvent GPL requirements is to publish a binary, but only publish select parts of the source code that built that binary.  Since you aren't publishing a binary, that doesn't affect you.

Another source of confusion is that depending on if your use of the proprietary library counts as your supervisor distributing a derivative work of Octave, the library may have to be published as GPL, but that's not your concern.